# JSTree race condition where AJAX success callback may have the wrong node

Tags: jquery, jstree, race-condition

I have a json_data implementation for jstree that allows a user to open up different nodes in a tree and view the contents.  Essentially this:

```
               .jstree({
                "plugins" : [ "json_data", "ui" ],
                "ui" : { "select_multiple_modifier": "on",
                         "selected_parent_close": "deselect" },
                "json_data" : {
                    "ajax" : {
                        "url": function(node) {
                            ... return a url ...
                        },
                        "success": function(metadata, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            var parent = this._get_node();  // <- RACE CONDITION
                            return parseMetaDataNodes(metadata, parent);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

If a user somehow clicks two nodes before the AJAX response for the first returns, it will think they both have the same "parent" in the tree, breaking behavior.

Does anyone know either:

1. A better way to get the correct node in the *success* callback?
2. A way to lock up the tree so it doesn't accept clicks until the first one returns? (Less desirable, but may work too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem, and I ended up going with your second solution, namely to prevent further select_node functions from executing until a flag is cleared:

```
 $("#treeHost").jstree({Your Plugin setup code}).bind("before.jstree", function(event, data) {
                if (data.func == "select_node" && !canSelectNodes) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            })
```

According to the official documentation, `before.jstree` is a special event you can bind to prevent operations from executing.  I check to see if the function be executed is `select_node`, and if it is, don't execute it if `canSelectNodes` is false.

This way, you can toggle `canSelectNodes` flag true of false elsewhere in your code to prevent the tree from accepting node selections.

Comment: That does the job, and it's not as bad a user experience as I thought, particularly since JSTree caches the nodes once it builds them, so deselecting and reselecting is fast.  Comment creds on the open source project this is in: https://github.com/carterpage/yoga/commit/aef8b68fe9eeb71f302e2bfc1b916e357330b717